# Why imagecreatefromstring returns a resource with invalid pointer?

Tags: php, gd, flysystem

This is my scenario:

I receive a base64 image and my goal is to upload a jpg to S3 through the [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/) library. I'm on Symfony 3.3.9.

Actually I reiceive this error when I try to use the writeStream method.

> ftell(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in
>   /opt/project/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Util.php line 250

Here's my code

```
$data = explode(',', $base64String, 2);

$relativePath = 'here/there.jpg';

$imageDecoded = base64_decode($data[1]);

$imageResource = imagecreatefromstring($imageDecoded);

$s3FileSystem->writeStream($relativePath, $imageResource,
['visibility' => AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC,
 'mimetype' => 'image/jpeg',
]);
```

Reading the docs of ftell() it says

> The file pointer must be valid, and must point to a file successfully
>   opened by fopen or popen.

How can I avoid this error? Should I save before the image to a file and after use fopen on it?

BTW I tried to save the image and it is correct, so no corrupt data.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `imagecreatefromstring` creates a gd image resource, not a file handle.

Comment: Hi @deceze, so the only solution is save the resource to a file and after open it with fopen?

Comment: You could write to a `php://memory` stream too; or look for a method on `$s3FileSystem` that accepts a string, I don't know whether that exists.